# chrome.storage.local strange behaviour: confused by a duplicate object

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After a lot of bug-hunting, I managed to narrow my problem down to this bit of code:

```
dup = {a: [1]}
chrome.storage.local.set({x: [dup, dup]});
chrome.storage.local.get(["x"], function(o) {console.log(JSON.stringify(o['x']));});
```

This prints out: `[{"a":[1]},null]`

Which I find to be a pretty strange behaviour. So my questions are:

1. Is this intentional? Is it documented?
2. Can you recommend a good solution to bypass this limitation?

My current idea is to use JSON.stringify (which handles this case correctly) and later parse the string. But that just seems wasteful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No it is not intentional and should be [reported](https://crbug.com/new) as a bug: https://crbug.com/606955 (and now it is fixed as of Chrome 52!).
2. As I explained in the bug report, the cause of the bug is that the objects are identical. If your object `dup` only contains simple values (i.e. no nested arrays or objects, only primitive values such as strings, numbers, booleans, null, ...), then a shallow clone of the object is sufficient:

   ```js
   dup = {a: [1]}
   dup2 = Object.assign({}, dup);
   chrome.storage.local.set({x: [dup, dup2]});
   ```

   If you need support for nested objects, then you have to make a deep clone. There are many existing libraries or code snippets for that, so I won't repeat it here. A simple way to prepare values for [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is by serializing it to JSON and then parsing it again (then all objects are unique).

   ```js
   dup = {a: [1]}
   var valueToSave = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([dup, dup]));
   chrome.storage.local.set({x: valueToSave});

   // Or:
   var valueToSave = [ dup, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dup)) ];
   chrome.storage.local.set({x: valueToSave});
   ```

Comment: i think the issue is not considering the async nature of the api, and not an actual issue

Comment: @ZigMandel Although you should not rely on it, getting a value after storing it is currently synchronous. Even if you take the asynchronous nature into account (as I did in the bug report), the bug still shows up. And I actually checked the [source code of Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/c864f52514c7e8cf9992a524e0294b1cc32c1db5/content/child/v8_value_converter_impl.cc#457) (the `UpdateAndCheckUniqueness` part is the culprit) and found evidence that there is an implementation flaw (see bug report for details).

Comment: There is no JSON.serialize in chrome. Did you mean stringify?